# Proof that subcomplex of a CW complex is a CW complex

Tags: general-topology, cw-complexes

The following proof is taken from *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* by John Lee. There is another question on this proof but it does not address my query.
[image: proof]

I would like to ask about the third sentence. Since $e\subseteq Y$ is a cell, by definition of the subcomplex, $Y$ contains the closure $\overline{e}$. The 'C' in CW implies that the closure of $e$ intersects finitely many cells (since it is contained in the union of finitely many cells). But I'm unsure as to why this implies that the cells of $X$ that $\overline{e}$ intersects has to be cells of $Y$ too?

Comment: This really depends on the specific definition of CW complex and sub-complex, which we don't have. But the C in CW doesn't imply anything, the only thing which implies anything is the definitions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am using Lee's definitions of CW complex and sub-complex.

Comment: Right, I figured Lee's book would be using the definitions from Lee's book, but there are many people here who don't have Lee's book, so you are greatly restricting the potential people who can help you by posting this question without the definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has not too much to do with topological issues; it is more just a set theoretical consequence of a few facts about $Y$ that follow from the definition of subcomplex.

By definition of subcomplex, $Y$ is a union of cells of $X$. And since the cells of $X$ are pairwise disjoint, for each cell $e'$ of $X$ it follows that either $e' \cap Y = \emptyset$ or $e' \subset Y$.

So for each cell $e'$ of $X$, if there exists $x \in e'$ such that $x \in Y$ then it follows that $e' \subset Y$.

For each cell $e$ of $X$ such that $e \subset Y$ and for each $x \in \overline{e}$, as you say it follows from the definition of a subcomplex that $x \in Y$. Letting $e'$ be the unique cell of $X$ such that $x \in e'$, it then follows from the argument above that $e' \subset Y$.

Comment: Thank you! Much simpler than I thought.